# Does Windows Store accept appxbundle for a UWP Application?

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, uwp, windows-store

This may be a trivial question but the following articles suggest that I can only upload **AppxUpload** for the Windows 10/UWP applications to the Windows Store.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/publish/upload-app-packages

http://developerpublish.com/uwp-tips-tricks-6-acceptance-validation-error-you-cannot-submit-pre-compiled-net-native-packages/

I know that I can sideload applications on to my Windows Phone using the generated **Appx** or **AppxBundle**  but my question is that **can I upload appxbundle for Windows 10/UWP applications to the store ?**

I tried uploading **AppxBundle** for my UWP Application but I get the following error:

[image]

where as when I use **Appxupload**, the store accepts it and there is no issue. But we want to upload **AppxBundle** (in any case). Please guide for the same.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

According to this article, you should use the **.appxupload** file, 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh454036.aspx

I was able to upload the *.appxbounle* package to the Windows 8.1 Store, *I'm not sure* what if it's been removed or not... you could try to turn on/off the .NET Native compiler and then upload the bundle package.. (Your project properties > Build > Use .Net Native tool chain)

Comment: Yes! Even  I had uploaded _appxbundle_ for Windows 8.1, but I am not sure about the UWP, many articles suggest that you can only upload _appxupload_ but I will try what you suggested and update here

Comment: Why do you NOT want to upload the Appxupload  ?